# What motivates my rivals during Conquests?

Tags: story-of-seasons

When competing for a field, the player can choose to compete in a festival or  compete via shipping. For the shipping options, what determines how much my rivals ship?

If an exact formula isn't known, it would still be useful to know which factors definitely do or definitely do not affect a rival's performance.

Answer (score -3):

I can't say very much, but what I do know is that many things in this game are random; like contests. If you save right before a contest and you don't win, you can restart your game and get different results, eventually winning (I did this last night).